# Most efficient way to do Parallax in an HTML5 Game

Tags: javascript, performance, html5-canvas, game-engine, parallax

Is it better to draw each Background Layer onto different Canvases and then move them around or is it better to redraw them each frame ?

I have to draw them on canvases since my Game is tile based and the background gets build from tiles.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you can do tile-based games with SVG or even just HTML using divs with background images.

Comment: Yes, i did it with divs before i used Canvas but it was not performant. And it could not even run at 60 fps.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, parallax is 2+ images moving at different speeds.

So the general efficiency rule of *"Put like-speed animations on their own canvas"* applies.

For example:

- Your background may move once every 3 frames.
- Your characters may move every frame.

Savings == 2 background draws every 3 frames (quite a good savings!)